# Achemso: Can I remove the "S"1 from the bibliography in supporting information of the achemso package, manuscipt=suppinfo

Tags: achemso

I am compiling my supporting information for a paper, and I am using the `manuscript=suppinfo` from the `achemso` package, which labels all of my figures and such with `S1`, which is great. The problem is that my bibliography is also listed as `S1,S2,..`etc, is there an easy way to remove the "S" from the bibliography?

Would it be simpler to not use the `manuscipt=suppinfo` and simply add

```
renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

type of a command to add the "S" where I need it?

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
\AtBeginDocument
  {%
    \renewcommand*{\citenumfont}[1]{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\bibnumfmt}[1]{(#1)}%
  }
```

(`achemso` sets up the 'S' using the same method, but provided you do this after loading the class all will be well.)